# HTML e-mail with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have got a contact form that is able to output the Message ($message) easily, but I have added other variables eg. date, party etc.  These appear correctly but i've tried adding HTML code to make the output more structured but all it does is print the HTML code!

Please help if you can, see code below.  The Line that needs work is:

```
mail( "theresa.pert@me.com", "VoH Online Enquiry",
   "Name: $name.</p>, Telephone Number: $telephone, Tour Date: $date, No in Party: $party,    Message: $message","From: $email");


<?php
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $name  = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
  $telephone = $_REQUEST['telephone'] ;
  $date = $_REQUEST['date'] ;
  $party = $_REQUEST['party'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;


if (!isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
  header( "Location: ../contact.shtml" );
}
elseif (empty($email) || empty($message)) {
  header( "Location: ../contact-error.shtml" );
 }
   else {
   mail( "theresa.pert@me.com", "VoH Online Enquiry",
   "Name: <p>$name</p> <p>Telephone Number: $telephone</p> <p>Tour Date: $date</p> <p>No in Party: $party</p><p>Message: $message</p>","From: $email");
    header( "Location: ../contact-thankyou.shtml" );
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: You'll need to indicate somehow that they MIME type of the e-mail is text/html.  Absent that indication, an e-mail would be treated as plain text, which appears to be what is happening here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send html table in email body in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160320/how-to-send-html-table-in-email-body-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the header in the mail function:

```
        $headers = "Reply-To: .... <mail@blabla.blabla>\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "Return-Path: .... <mail@blabla.blabla>\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "From:  .... <mail@blabla.blabla>\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "Organization: .... <mail@blabla.blabla>\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";  
            mail($email, $object, $text, $headers);
```

Take a look at the [Mail](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) docs

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help. The code works correctly (i receive an email with the content in it) I just need to format it so that it appears on seperate lines.