# Cron Job to Email Table

Tags: cron

I want to setup a cron job (I think this is my best option) to automatically email me a table of open orders from my mySQL DB each morning.
I have a php page which displays the table, and I was hoping to just be able to use that.  However, as most of you probably know what happened, it ran the file and emailed me all the html as text (yes my gMail allows html emails).
What do I need to look up to create my table and email it to me.
thanks.

Comment: Perfect.  got it to work with what Matt mentioned below and then the answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160320/how-to-send-html-table-in-email-body-in-php, to generate my table to be emailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are invoking somewhere in your PHP code something like the following:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

If so, check a couple basic things:

1. Your $message variable begins with:

   ```
   <html>
   ```
2. Your $message variable ends with:

   ```
   </html>
   ```
3. You've added the HTML content type to your message headers, for example using the code:

   ```
   $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
   ```

Comment: thanks.  I wasn't originally because I was using the cron job manager on my GoDaddy Console.  It had the option to email results of job to my email.  I was just thinking that adding the mail function may help.  I'll add it in and see what happens.
thanks.